# Compilation Error in MVC3 custom WebViewPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use my own `WebViewPage` in MVC3 and When I create an abstract class with specific name and change the `WebViewPage` to my own type in Web.config, I get this error:

```
 Compiler Error Message: CS0308: The non-generic type 'Aya.Moj.Web.Controllers.MojWebViewPage' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Custom `WebViewPage` code:

```
namespace Aya.Moj.Web.Controllers
{
    public abstract class MojWebViewPage : WebViewPage
    {
        //just for test
        public string Boo { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should inherit from `WebViewPage<TModel>` because you're going to pass a Model to this `WebViewPage`
Then your `WebViewPage` will look like this :

```
namespace Aya.Moj.Web.Controllers
{
    public abstract class MojWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
    {
        //just for test
        public string Boo { set; get; }
    }
}
```